# How to make a method for image scaling using the closest neighbor system

Tags: java, image

the method starts with and its supposed to return an array of size `[img[0].length*factor_h]*[img.length*factor_w]`

```
public static int[][] scaleup(double factor_j,double factor_w,int [][]img)}//the method
    int[][] answer= new int[img.length][img[0].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < img[0].length; j++) {
            for (int f_w = 0; f_w<=img[0].length; f_w++) {//f_w is smaller than the factor_w
                for (int f_h = 0; f_h <= img.length; f_h++) {
                    answer[(int) (i * factor_h) + f_h][(int) (j * factor_w) + f_w] = img[j][i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return answer;
    }
}
```

im having trouble making this method to work but it goes out of bounds

Comment: Please make you code clearer by using more meaningful variables or more comments

Answer (score 0):

your problem lies in this line:

```
int[][] answer= new int[img.length][img[0].length];
```

there you say your answer has the same size as your old img (let us assume 64x64 as an example). So you have now an array 64x64. So the last field/pixel is `answer[63][63]`.

In this line of code:

```
answer[(int) (i * factor_h) + f_h][(int) (j * factor_w) + f_w] = img[j][i];
```

you say the first index is `i * factor_h + f_h`.

your variable `i` goes from 0 to 63 and your `f_h` goes from 0 to 64.

I don't think you can choose a `factor_h` that you won't get an out of bound error at all. So yeah initialize your answer array in the right way otherwise it won't work.

The same for the 2nd index as well with `j` and `factor_w` / `f_w`.

Comment: Thank it was  very useful

Comment: public static int[][] scaleup(double factor_h, double factor_w, int[][] im) {
  
  int[][] answer= new int[(int)(im.length*factor_h)+1][(int)(im[0].length*factor_w)+1];
  for (int i = 0; i < im.length; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < im[0].length; j++) {
    for (int f_w = 0; f_w<factor_h; f_w++) {
     for (int f_h = 0; f_h < factor_w; f_h++) {
      answer[(int) (i * factor_h + f_w)][(int) (j * factor_w + f_h)] = im[i][j];
     }
    }
   }
  }
  return answer;
 }

}

Comment: if it solved the problem please accept it as answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[][] scaleup(double factor_h, double factor_w, int[][] im) {

    int[][] answer = new int[(int) (im.length * factor_h) + 1][(int) (im[0].length * factor_w) + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < im.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < im[0].length; j++) {
            for (int f_w = 0; f_w < factor_h; f_w++) {
                for (int f_h = 0; f_h < factor_w; f_h++) {
                    answer[(int) (i * factor_h + f_w)][(int) (j * factor_w + f_h)] = im[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```